# A problem of minimum

Tags: calculus, derivatives

**Problem**: Among all rectangular parallelepipeds having for base a square and of constant volume $V$, determine the one of minimum total area also has diagonal of minimum length.

**Solution**: Given $x$ and $y$ as the respective measurements of the base edge and height, the volume $V$ is given by $V=x^2y \iff y = \frac{V}{x^2}$.

In principle there is nothing to prevent the base edge from being as large as
as desired, so it must be $x ≥ 0$. The total area will be the sum of the two bases i.e. $2x^2$ and of the lateral faces $4xy$ so

$$S(x)=2x^2+4\frac{V}{x}$$
The derivate is:

$$S'(x)=\frac{4(x^3-V)}{x^2}$$
cancel if $x=\sqrt[3]{V}$. The corresponding value of $y$ is $$y=\frac{V}{\sqrt[3]{V^2}}=x$$  so the solution is
a cube. That it is a minimum is confirmed by the range of positivity of the first derivative,
given by the inequality $x>\sqrt[3]{V}$. For $x$ between $0$ and $\sqrt[3]{V}$ the derivative is negative, which
confirms that it is a point of minimum.

**Question**: How can I determine the one of minimum total area **also has diagonal of minimum length**?

Comment: Can you assume that the parallelepiped is rectangular?

Comment: @paw88789 yes...

Comment: Don't just answer that in a comment. Edit your question to fix that omission.

Comment: @jjagmath Done, I have edited my question. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can search for the minimum of the square of the diagonal as well. Call it $D\left(x\right)$.

We have $$D\left(x\right)=x^2+x^2+y^2=2x^2+\frac{V^2}{x^4}$$ with derivative
$$
D'\left(x\right) = 4x-4\frac{V^2}{x^5}
= \frac{4\left(x^6-V^2\right)}{x^5}
= \frac{4\left(x^3-V\right)\left(x^3+V\right)}{x^5}
$$
that equals $0$ when $x=\sqrt[3]{V}$ (considering that $x>0$).

Since
$$
D''\left(x\right) = 4+20\frac{V^2}{x^6}>0
$$
then $D$ attains a minimum at $x=\sqrt[3]{V}$.

The minimum is attained when the total area attains a minimum too, as claimed.

Comment: Thank you very very much.